Rebooting into Ubuntu without using BIOS settings
I have a remote PC(connected through team viewer) setup with Ubuntu 22 and Windows 11, the boot priority is set to boot into windows. Currently I am booted into Ubuntu 22, due a CUDA issue I have to reboot my PC. As there isn't any one to access the PC physically for now, is there any way to change the boot priority from Ubuntu itself so that it would reboots back into Ubuntu again. And the catch is I have only one try , if it fails, it will boot into Windows and we will have remote access still, but I don't want that to happen.
Thanks,
I went through the GRUB settings, and it is already set to '0' as shown below,
GRUB_DEFAULT=0 GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Note: Below is the issue which i have with CUDA, if anyone knows a way to fix it without reboot, that will also work.
I have setup AlexyAB Darknet YoloV4, it has been working fine, but all of a sudden today I have the following error. Last time when i had the same, I had to reboot the system and it worked fine.
Error:
Darknet error location: ./src/dark_cuda.c, cuda_set_device(), line #38 CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected: Bad file descriptor backtrace (8 entries) 1/8: ./darknet(log_backtrace+0x38) [0x5593a5171208] 2/8: ./darknet(error+0x3d) [0x5593a51712ed] 3/8: ./darknet(check_error+0xd0) [0x5593a5173be0] 4/8: ./darknet(check_error_extended+0x7c) [0x5593a5173ccc] 5/8: ./darknet(main+0x28d) [0x5593a51306cd] 6/8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x29d90) [0x7f61655d4d90] 7/8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x80) [0x7f61655d4e40] 8/8: ./darknet(_start+0x25) [0x5593a51329f5]

output for "nvcc --version" :  nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation Built on Fri_Sep__8_19:17:24_PDT_2023 Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.52 Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33281558_0

Since you have Windows 11, your system must boot in UEFI style. Therefore, you should be able to view your boot order and other boot settings in Linux using the sudo efibootmgr -v command.
It should output something like this:
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0002,0000,0006,0005,0001,0003,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.8.7.6.5.4.3.2.-.1.0.f.e.-.d.c.b.a.-.9.8.7.6.-.5.4.3.2.1.0.f.e.d.c.b.a.}...d................
Boot0001* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive     BBS(129,,0x0)
Boot0002* rEFInd Boot Manager   HD(1,GPT,12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\REFIND\REFIND_X64.EFI)
Boot0003* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0)
Boot0004* debian        HD(1,GPT,12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\DEBIAN\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0005* UEFI: PXE IP4 Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x6)/MAC(0123456789ab,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO


The BootCurrent: line indicates the number of the BootNNNN line that was used to boot the current operating system.
The BootOrder: line specifies the order in which the various boot targets specified on BootNNNN lines are tried when booting the system
The UUID string 12345678-9abc-def0-1234-56789abcdef0 is the actual PARTUUID of the ESP partition that contains the bootloader files specified on the individual BootNNNN lines.

In this example, Windows' native boot manager is option Boot0000, so if the system was set to boot into Windows by default, the BootOrder would have 0000 as the first entry. If GRUB is configured to boot Ubuntu by default, then the "boot into Windows by default" setting must be in UEFI boot settings.
This example system is currently configured to boot into Debian by default, and that's how it was started to produce the example output.
To tell your system to boot into Ubuntu just once, you can use sudo efibootmgr --bootnext NNNN where NNNN is the BootNNNN number of the line that runs Ubuntu's GRUB.
To tell your system to keep defaulting to Ubuntu until specifically instructed otherwise, use sudo efibootmgr --bootorder XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ.... where the XXXX,YYYY,ZZZZ are the numbers of the boot options currently listed on the BootOrder: line, rearranged so that the number of Ubuntu's line is the first one.
In other words, to make this example system to boot into Windows just once, and then back to the default Debian on subsequent boots:
sudo efibootmgr --bootnext 0000

To make the example system boot into Windows until the settings are changed again:
sudo efibootmgr --bootorder 0000,0004,0002,0006,0005,0001,0003,0007

You can in theory leave out unwanted entries from the boot order line, but some buggy UEFI implementations may then add any left-out entries back into the tail end of the boot order, in some random ordering. It has been my experience that it's safest to just rearrange the boot order instead of shortening or extending it, if there is no acute need to do otherwise.

Thanks telcoM,
Your solution worked. BootCurrent was 1000, Windows Boot Manager was 0000.
With sudo efibootmgr --bootnext 1000 I was able to reboot into Ubuntu Again.
